# How can I tell which expansion packs were activated for a particular town?

Tags: pc, the-sims-3

As you know, you can pick which expansion packs to play with in a Sims 3 game. And for me, I use different ones for different towns (save files).

Now, I want to go back to an older save, but I can't remember what I had activated. Is there a way to see which packs were activated?

I don't just want to activate all the packs since my PC isn't going to handle that well.